# What's the significance of ice pop lottery?

Tags: yosuga-no-sora

During the series, Akira Amatsume discusses an ice-pop/popsicle lottery. The winner obtains a wooden stick with some words printed on it. However, later on Akira mentions that it is just a urban myth.

What is the significance of this plot point? Does the lottery relate to a real urban myth? Is the lottery a symbol for something?